# Dismiss a pop up view

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a popup view programmatically and when I click the button in the popup, it will show another alert view controller. But the problem is I can't dismiss the initially added pop up view. It still shows behind the alert view. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Using the below code, I have created the popup view.

```
   let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
        let menuViewController: PopupViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Popup") as! PopupViewController
        menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        menuViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 275)

        let popoverMenuViewController = menuViewController.popoverPresentationController
        popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
        popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = self.view
        // If wants the arrow head remove the below line code
        popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
        popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds),0,0)
        presentViewController(menuViewController,animated: true,completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please add your code for popup view and how you dismiss

Comment: Maybe you should pop it before alert shows.

Comment: As in the above code, I have created the first popup view. Then I added a OK button inside the popup view. Once the user clicks the OK button it will display another alert view programmatically. The above scenario works fine. But the problem is I want to hide/ dismiss the first popup view while displaying the second alert view. Since, I'm creating the second view inside the OK button event, I can't dissmiss the popup view. Is it impossible to do???

Answer (score 0):

That's may helps you

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "My alert", message: "some text...", preferredStyle: .Alert)
// .Default will dismiss the alert automatically
let myAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Alert", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
    // Some stuff, present your other alert
    // self.myMainViewController.presentViewController...
 })
alertController.addAction(myAlertAction)
```

That's how I do, and it works fine

Comment: Using the below code I have created the pop up view.

Comment: Thank you. But the second alert view is not showing up once I used the above code.

Comment: Are you trying to launch an alert view from your popup view ? If yes, try to instanciate your second view from your main controller, not your popup. Cause your popup will be raised from the memory and your alert will not be shown

Comment: If those views are not controllers, you can do it by `self.view.addSubview()` method.

Comment: Actually those views are controllers. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Your can try this by `mainVc.addChildViewController()` (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691029/what-is-the-correct-way-to-display-multiple-viewcontrollers-view-hierarchy-in-a)

Comment: Thank you for ur support. Solved it by using unwind segue.